# poblar array con string recibido metodo de post

Tags: php, json

Tengo un script en javascript, que al ejecutarlo me envía esta información por post:

```
array(1) {  ["data"]=>  string(36) "[name:jorge,apellido:nieves,edad:31]"}
```

pero no se como capturarla y poblar un array:

```
$info=[];
foreach($_POST['data'] as $key => $value){
    $info[$key]=$value;
}
```

Comment: ¿ese código marca algún error o qué hace?

Comment: Al parecer tu array no tiene el formato correcto como lo envias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No podrás poblar el array porque estas iterando un string:

`string(36) "[name:jorge,apellido:nieves,edad:31]"`

**Editar la manera en la que envias la información por javascript**, hará que el código php funcione, supondré que usas ajax:

```
$.post( url, { data: { name: 'jorge', apellido: 'nieves', edad: '31' } } );
```

De esta manera la variable `$_POST['data']` tendrá el siguiente valor:

`array(3) {  ["nombre"]=>  string(5) "jorge", ["apellido"]=>  string(6) "nieves", ["edad"]=>  string(2) "31"}`

Comment: gracias reviso y te aviso si funciona

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuestas aceptada, para ayuda de los que tengan tengan el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que el error es que no es capaz de recorrer el array `$_POST`. Esto puede ocurrir porque no hayas cargado la variable `$_POST`.

Me explico, si no utilizas ningún framework PHP, es decir, utilizas PHP nativo, los array `$_POST, $_GET, ...` no se cargan en el controlador de forma automática. Realmente el contenido de estos arrays se encuentra dentro del array `$GLOBALS` que contiene las variables globales de tu fichero PHP.

El código para que el bucle funcione sería el siguiente:

```
$info=[];
$_POST = $GLOBALS['_POST'];

foreach($_POST['data'] as $key => $value){
    $info[$key]=$value;
}
```